# Large try except block in Python - how to understand where was an exception?

Tags: python, exception

I have a program (not mine) that has a large try - except block.
Somewhere in this block there is an exception. 
what is the best way to find out the exact string of code where it happens?

Comment: Use debugger or print exception in except block

Comment: However it is better to avoid large try/except block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [print_exc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc) in the `except` block

```
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

**Example:**

```
import traceback
try:
    pass
    pass
    pass
    pass
    pass
    raise NameError("I dont like your name")
    pass
    pass
    pass
    pass
    pass
except Exception, e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise NameError("I dont like your name")
NameError: I dont like your name
```

Comment: Hm.. What's the difference with just re-raising it?

Comment: @aIKid Actually, after answering this, I was really wondering, by default python provides this traceback, right?

Comment: Not if you catch the exception.

Comment: @user2357112 In that case, re-raising itself is also enough, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye Exactly. `e.message` does the same thing as well.

Comment: @aIKid Why don't you put that as an answer? :)

Comment: Depends. If you want the exception to always halt the program, there shouldn't be a try-except at all. However, commenting out the `except` block and replacing it with a bare `raise` is okay as a temporary measure.

Comment: I don't want to reraise the exception, because it will interfere with some other logic in upper level. I just want to figure out the behavour.

Comment: @bespark Posted what you probably wanted as an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, if you don't want an exception to be raised, you can just have the error message, then pass:

```
>>> try:
    raise ValueError("A stupid error has occurred")
except Exception as e:
    the_error = str(e)
    pass

>>> the_error
'A stupid error has occurred'
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is exactly the first answer. Your answer is valuable too.